# Is there a way to search for text in the ipython qtconsole?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm using ipython with qtconsole.
A feature I'm missing from the regular console is to search the console output.
I'd expect to see it under the Edit menu.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can search your previous commands with `%hist -g foo`. I don't think there's a way to search your output yet, but if you want to write one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of that feature, but you can take advantage of the `Out` variable (also available as `_oh`) that is automatically exposed in the ipython console. Basically it's a dictionary in which the keys are the line numbers for which some kind of result was returned and the values are the results themselves. Hence, if you look for something in `Out.values()` using any python code you prefer should be useful to find what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, I know about the Out variable. I was hoping there was something in the qtconsole itself